# Should we use SSG for deploying a dashboard created using Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

We are going to develop a dashboard for internal use using Nuxt.js. As this will be an internal dashboard there is no need for a universal mode. Generally most of the dashboard are developed in SPA.

But SPA also requires a server to send the initial HTML and js bundle to the browser. So what if we use SSG and deploy it to s3 as it will no longer need a server and we can save the cost?

Answer (score 1):

You can totally `target: 'static'` and `ssr: false` and deploy your app to Netlify for free.
You don't need a Node.js server because you'll be serving static JS files only (generated during build time). So, only a CDN is enough (basically Netlify).

Also, do you use the other parts of Nuxt here? Nuxt's main benefit is the universal mode. Of course, it has other advantages but you could use Vitesse or vanilla Vue3 if you want to move a bit quicker (Nuxt3 allows for the usage of Vue3, Nuxt2 is focused on Vue2 only).